# Qt - Clearing QTableView's contents

Tags: c++, qt, model, qtableview

I am working in Qt 4.7, and have a dialog containing (among other, unrelated things) a QTableView and a QButton. When the QButton is clicked, it must clear all the data from the QTableView. I am unsure on how to accompish this. I've looked around online for a while, but haven't found anything too helpful. Based on what I found [here](http://www.qtforum.org/article/29523/clearing-the-tableview.html), I tried this:

`void MyClass::on_myButton_clicked()
{
  myTableView->model()->clear();
}`

However, this gave the following error:

```
error: C2039: 'clear' : is not a member of 'QAbstractItemModel'
```

Is there another way to do this that I am accidentally overlooking? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function `myTableView->model()` returns a `QAbstractItemModel` which does not contain the `clear()` method. You should call clear method of your model. If you have a model like:

```
QStandardItemModel * model= new QStandardItemModel( 2, 4 );
```

Calling clear should delete all data from the model erasing the view as a consequence as it is provided to show data in the associated model:

```
model->clear();
```

Answer (score 10):

I would reset the model (if you do not need the data in the model later).
Subclass your model (if it is a custom one) and implement a slot like;

```
void clear(){
   this->beginResetModel();
   ... // clear the content of your model here
   this->endResetModel();
{
```

Just check [QAbstractItemView::reset()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#reset).

Comment: The link you've posted is dead now.

Comment: Updated dead link